# How to take the address bar out of focus on page load?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, focus, address-bar, omnibox

Okay so basically I made a new tab extension that is pretty basic and I added a google search bar using inputs, it works perfectly and looks beautiful however when I open a new tab it auto focuses on the chrome address bar, is there any way to make it auto focus on my input?

Hitting tab once works to easily go from the address bar to the input so I tried simulating a tab click on page load however that doesn't seem to work, I could simply be doing it wrong, I know that there are chrome rules on this I was wondering if anyone found any type of work around, maybe some third party software that could hit the tab key whenever I open a new tab, im open to any ideas

Comment: you could use [`.focus()`](https://api.jquery.com/focus/)

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately overriding chromes auto focus on its address bar isn't that simple